# Grails validation error from service method

Tags: service, grails-validation

I have a method in a service class that creates an object:

```
def createContent (fileName, description) {

    def content = new Content(
        fileName:fileName,
        description:description,
    ).save()
}
```

Neither of those properties are nullable.  How can I pass the validation errors back to be displayed?  I've tried flash.message and render, both of which don't work from within service classes.  I also tried
    .save(failOnError:true)
which displayed a long list of errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplifying everything it should look like this.

Service method:

```
def createContent (fileName, description) {
    //creating an object to save
    def content = new Content(
        fileName:fileName,
        description:description,
    )

    //saving the object
    //if saved then savedContent is saved domain with generated id
    //if not saved then savedContent is null and content has validation information inside
    def savedContent = content.save()

    if (savedContent != null) {
        return savedContent
    } else {
        return content
    }
}
```

Now in controller:

```
def someAction = {
    ...
    def content = someService.createContent (fileName, description)
    if (content.hasErrors()) {
        //not saved
        //render create page once again and use content object to render errors
        render(view:'someAction', model:[content:content])
    } else {
        //saved
        //redirect to show page or something
        redirect(action:'show', model:[id:content.id])
    }
}
```

And someAction.gsp:

```
<g:hasErrors bean="${content}">
   <g:renderErrors bean="${content}" as="list" />
</g:hasErrors>
```

And in general you should look through this: [Grails validation doc](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/guide/7.%20Validation.html)